# How to obtain a gift from another player in Fantasy Life?

Tags: streetpass, fantasy-life

Today I streetpassed someone, who also played Fantasy Life. I went to the streetpass-clerk in the game, and I can see the profile of that other person. I saw that she had a gift, Black Onyx. But how do I get this item? I don't see it in my inventory, nor does the clerk have any option that will give it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do is to get the player into your town.  You do this by going to the StreetPass Clerk in the Guild Office.

Next, you need to find the Mii hanging out around town (not sure if they are found in towns other than the starting one).  You can sort-of use the map by looking for blue dots indicating a streetpass Mii's location, but they are not set and will appear in multiple locations.

Talk with the visiting Mii and you will increase your friendship with them.

Leave town and return to re-set the Mii's position and allow you to continue talking with them.

Once your friendship with them is at 100%, they will give you their item.

Comment: One thing to note is that you can actually get the item multiple times if you streetpass the person again after you've already received the item from them.  This is useful for duplicating hard-to-get or high-cost items if you have someone you play the game with regularly.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. For future visitors, quick travelling to the guild office also reset the position. I only found the visitors inside the inner three parts of town: shopping, main and artisan (I think they are called that, its where the cook, guild office and blacksmith is located respectively)